# jquery image slide

Tags: jquery

I have an image in the center and a bunch of images also in the center hidden, what I want to happen when I click next is the image from the center moves to the left (position.left currently - 250px ) and I want the next image to be moved to (current position + 250) and then animated (left -250px and displayed) so it works like when you click next it moves thee off the screen and moves the next image onto the screen.

I have it currently working, however when the animation finishes the image jumps another 250pixels left for some reason? (has the style left: -250px;)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#center-photo img:first').show();
    var imglist = $("#center-photo img");

    $('#next').click(function() {
        var active = $('#center-photo img:first');
        var next = active.next();
        var pos = $('#center-photo img:first').position();
        //Move current image out
        active
        .animate(
        { left: pos.left-250 + "px", opacity: 'hide' }, {
            duration: 'slow',
        });

        // Display next one and move in
        next.css('left', pos.left+0 + "px");

        next
        .animate(
        { left: pos.left-250 + "px", opacity: 'show' }, {
            duration: 'slow',
        });
    });
});
```

It looks fine while animating, it works properly up until the end when it jumps to -250px rather then staying in the position at the end of the animation.

How can I fix this?

Example: http://dubcanada.net/play/ex1/test.html

Comment: It's helpful to post the HTML that goes with this, or even better, a working demo page.

Comment: Done, http://dubcanada.net/play/ex1/test.html

Comment: Converted that to a fiddle for ease of messing about with: http://jsfiddle.net/qspSU/

Comment: Do you want the animations to happen together, or it to fly off to one side, *then* come in from the other side?

Comment: Did all that (my answer) make sense Steven, or do you need expansion on any of it?

Comment: Yup, that made perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you have a large number of issues with that code.

1. If you want the animations to happen sequentially, the second `animate()` call and setup need to go in the `complete` callback for the first `animate()` call.
2. The reason for the invalid positioning is that you are setting the `left` field of the object whilst it is `display: none` ie. hidden, this does not yield the correct results.  Set the opacity to 0, `show()` the next image and then set the `left` field, then animate in to position and visibility.
3. At no time are you rearranging the order of the images so the use of `$("#center-photo img:first")` is invalid, it will always get the same first image, and the `.next()` method will get the next entry in the DOM.  To fix this you need to find the currently visible image, and find the next in sequence to it, looping around to the beginning if desired.
4. You define `imglist`, but then repeatedly restate the selector, this is not a bug, but is unnecessary.

Here is corrected code, and I've added in the `#prev` method too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qspSU/2/

```
var speed = 'slow'; /* Change this to 5000 to see the movement more clearly */
var imglist = $("#center-photo img");
imglist.filter(':first').show();

$('#prev').click(function() {
    var active = imglist.filter(':visible');
    var prev = active.prev();

    if (prev.size() == 0) {
        prev = imglist.filter(':last');
    }

    var pos = active.position();

    //Move current image out
    active.animate(
        {
            left: (pos.left + 250),
            opacity: 'hide'
        },
        {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function() {
                // Display next one and move in
                prev.css('opacity', 0).show().css('left', (pos.left - 250) + "px");
                prev.animate(
                    {
                        left: pos.left,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        duration: speed
                    });
            }
        });
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    var active = imglist.filter(':visible');
    var next = active.next();

    if (next.size() == 0) {
        next = imglist.filter(':first');
    }

    var pos = active.position();

    //Move current image out
    active.animate(
        {
            left: (pos.left - 250),
            opacity: 'hide'
        },
        {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function() {
                // Display next one and move in
                next.css('opacity', 0).show().css('left', (pos.left + 250) + "px");
                next.animate(
                    {
                        left: pos.left,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        duration: speed
                    });
            }
        });
});
```

If you want them to happen simultaneously, then just take the contents of the function inside the `complete` callback property and put that at the same level as the first animation in each button click event.

***NB.*** One issue remains in the code, that is repetitive clicking can cause issues as the code is dependent on the current position and visibility of DIVs, so if one click executes before the end of another the positions can become maligned.  Use a semaphore/mutex variable to stop that from happening.